# Hiding Specific partition from a non-sudo user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition

Is there anyway to prevent a non-sudo user from seeing specific partition?
lets say "/data" partition?
I know that i can prevent the user from accessing the directory, but i preffer to hide it from the user.

is there any option like that?
Thanks

Comment: You could hide the folder if you put it below another folder where user no execute rights, but I don't think you can totally hide a partition: e.g. `lsblk`, `mount` or `df` work without `root` and show the partitions.

Comment: *partition* or *filesystem* / mount-point?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick answer @RoVo. yes im talking about mount or partition ( the one that we can hide , if possible) currently im looking for any solution , my problem is not about where to store the data (partition/mount) but to hide it from non-sudo user

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes im talking about mount or partition ( the one that we can hide , if possible) currently im looking for any solution , my problem is not about where to store the data (partition/mount) but to hide it from non-sudo use

Comment: You might want to investigate mount namespaces.  This won't give you the sudo vs non-sudo but it does let you "hide" a mount, making them only available to a particular group of processes.

Answer (score 0):

i wanted to achieve that when my support user is connected , he will not be able to see the "secret" partition.

I have achieved that by adding a "Maintenance mode" to the grub menu, from there the server will get loaded with a different run-level , and I've added a script to "umount" the secret partition while this run-level is getting loaded

Thanks for your answers!